# Can't read previously saved data from *.m files

Tags: octave

```
[layer1 layer2 layer3] = trainNeuralNetwork4L(tlab, tvec, clab, cvec, 150, 100, 10);
save layerOne100SECOND.m layer1
save layerTwo100SECOND.m layer2
save layerThree100SECOND.m layer3
[efficiency errorsMatrix] = testClassifier4L(layer1, layer2, layer3, 150, 100, 10, tstv, tstl)
1 min 55 s
efficiency =  0.96150
[....]
load "layerTwo100SECOND.m"
layerTwo100SECOND
parse error near line 6 of file /home/yob/studies/rob/lab5/src/layerTwo100SECOND.m

 syntax error

>>> 0.3555228566483329 1.434063629132475 0.3947326168010625 -0.2081288665103496 2.116026824600183 -3.72004826748463 -5.971912014167303 -1.831568668193203 -0.5698533706125537 -0.302019433067382 2.105773052363495 -1.386054572212726 1.379784981138861 2.086342965563345 1.686560884521974 1.501297857975125 5.491292848790862 -3.068496819708705 1.709375867569474 -0.0007631747244577478 -3.408706829842817 3.633531634060732 -4.848485685095641 -7.071386223304461 1.005495674207059 1.729698733795992 1.332654214742491 -2.757799109392227 0.5703177663227227 -3.962183321109198 -1.862612684812663 0.002426506616464667 -1.0133423788506 0.9856584491014603 3.261391305445486 -0.238792116035831 7.213403195852512 -0.4550088635822298 2.014786513359268 5.439781417403554 -1.780067076293333 -1.141234270367437 -3.716379329290984 1.329603499392993 0.6289460687541696 1.38704906311103 -1.799460630680088 -1.231927489757737 -1.199171465361949 6.464325931161664 0.7819466841352927 1.518220081499355 -0.3605511334486079 6.646043807207327 -1.885519415534916 1.164993883529136 -0.6867734922571105 -3.487015662787853 0.6052594571214193 0.9747958246654298 -6.681621035920442 6.539828816493673 0.4174688104699146 1.804835542540412 3.099980655618463 0.1957057586983393 -0.5199262355448695 -0.05556003295310553 0.5458621853042805 4.053727148988344 5.08596174444348 -4.4719975219626 4.718638484049811 4.579389030123606 -0.3683947372431971 0.9758069969974679 0.4742051227060113 6.761326112144753 0.9816521216523206 1.790072342537753 0.4513686207416066 -2.880053219384659 -3.256083938937911 3.099498881741825 -0.4967119404782309 -0.6140345297878478 -0.9933076418596357 7.522343253108136 4.93675021253316 -2.693878828387868 -1.358775970578509 -0.7940899801569826 4.867002040829598 4.418439759567837 -2.014761152547027 0.2349575211823655 -4.494720934106189 -2.674441246174409 -0.8495958842163256 0.1921793737146104
                                   ^
```

Why is it impossible to use previously saved data? Is there any way to use them one more time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I dealed with it. I had to call: `load -ascii filename`.